# MPChart BarChart: draw x axis line on zero value

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I am using MPChart for displaying a Barchart. My values are positive and negative. I want to show xAxis as used in Math of traditional way. Using this code my chart display vertical lines (only zero wanted)

```
mXAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
mXAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
mXAxis.setEnabled(false);

mYAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
mYAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);
mYAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
mYAxis.setStartAtZero(false);

mYAxisRight = mChart.getAxisRight();
mYAxisRight.setEnabled(false);
mYAxisRight.setDrawGridLines(false);
```

Please, provide some sample for removing all horizontal lines but zero

**EDIT:**
Even when `yAxis.setLabelCount(1)` (1 because zero value needed to shown) the impl looks like:

```
public void setLabelCount(int yCount) {
    if(yCount > 25) {
        yCount = 25;
    }

    if(yCount < 2) {
        yCount = 2;
    }

    this.mLabelCount = yCount;
}
```

So, is it recommended to override this implementation?

Comment: You got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

**I have got solution with labels at bottom**

> Use this in your code

```
mXAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
mXAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
mXAxis.setEnabled(true);
xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
```